# get preg_replace error with YAMS in Modx

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I have installed YAMS in my Modx installation. Run version 1.0.5 of Modx and 1.1.9 YAMS plugin.

It works on my clean installation of modx + yams but not on my existing site with content.
Are there any problem with the TV´s?

Answer (score 0):

I use both versions of MODX and YAMS with the latest version of PHP and I don't get any preg_replace error. But it can be a problem with different versions of PHP in different servers and with other snippets or plugins involved with YAMS